# grails create-controller junit tests rather than spock

Tags: grails, junit, spock

I am going through a few books on Grails 2 and all use junit in their unit tests but I notice that when I run create-controller, the auto generated unit tests are spock based.
Is it possible to have the script crate junit tests instead? I notice the only option for create-controller is the name of the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize all the generated artifacts by generating the templates:

```
grails install-templates
```

Then you'll find the template used to generate the test for the controller in:

```
src/templates/testing/Controller.groovy
```

You can then delete all other files, you don't want to adopt (under `src/templates` that is)

If you need inspiration for the "old" ones, look at the [source](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/2.2.x/grails-resources/src/grails/templates/testing/Controller.groovy)

If you also want to have the naming of the files like back in the days, you have to also reconstruct the [`createUnitTest`](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/2.2.x/scripts/_GrailsCreateArtifacts.groovy#L139) script.  Create/Add in your `scripts/_Events.groovy` file:

```
eventDefaultStart = {
    createUnitTest = { Map args = [:] ->
        def superClass = args["superClass"] ?: "GrailsUnitTestCase"
        createArtifact(
        name: args["name"],
        suffix: "${args['suffix']}Tests",
        type: args.testType ?: args['suffix'],
        path: "test/unit",
        superClass: superClass,
        templatePath:"templates/testing",
        skipPackagePrompt: args['skipPackagePrompt'])
    }
}
```

As you can see there is a var `templatePath`, that you can adjust, if you plan to use this alot (put your templates in your ~ e.g.)

Comment: I'd rather only deal with this hastle while reading that book and start adopting Spock.  It makes writing tests alot more [Gg]roovy.

Comment: I think you may be right - best to stick with Spock though yet another thing to learn. But many thanks for the full answer.